# After converting erb to slim, stops displaying the picture

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

I have an erb file that I want to convert to slim; after converting, the display of pictures stops.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to resolve this? I looked in the documentation and was unable to determine what to do next.

```
<div class='flex-container--galleria-and-rectangle'>
    <div class='galleria flex-item--galleria-and-rectangle'>
        <% @project.shuffle.first(6).each do |portfolio| %>
        <div class="flex-container" style="float:left">
            <div class='flex-item img-project rectangle-and-text-hover' style="background-image: url(<%= image_path(portfolio.image_url) %>)" >
                <a href='<%= portfolio.web_address %>' target="_blank">
```

---

```
section#portfolio
  .portfolio
    .container.content
      .col-xs-12
        .row
          .col-xs-10.col-xs-offset-1
            .title
              p.last last
              p.projects projects
        .row
          .col-xs-10.col-xs-offset-1
            .wrapper--galleria-rectangle
              .flex-container--galleria-and-rectangle
                .galleria.flex-item--galleria-and-rectangle
                  - @project.shuffle.first(6).each do |portfolio|
                    .flex-container style="float:left" 

                      = image_path(portfolio.image_url)
                      | )' &gt;
                      a href='' 
                      = portfolio.web_address
                      | ' target="_blank"&gt;
                      .flex-container-info
```

Comment: It looks like another version of this question that you also asked recently.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52438274/links-do-not-work-after-translation-into-slim-format

Comment: Yes, but the question is different, I wrote that I can not find it in the documentation, the question of another block, I beg you not to blame for the double.

Comment: How are you performing the conversion?

Comment: I go to the converter site and do the conversion, then links and images cease to work, if in the last question I understood how to establish links, then the image is not there.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this with below syntax

```
.flex-item.img-project.rectangle-and-text-hover{style: "background-image: url(#{image_path(portfolio.image_url)})"}
  %a{href: "#{portfolio.web_address}", target: "_blank"}
```